# Java cannot get Nodelist with french accents inside my XML

Tags: java, special-characters, nodelist

I have an XML like this one having french character:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<liste>
<produit code="311" prix="43.00" quantité= "28" />
<produit code="123" prix="39.00" quantité= "10"  />
<produit code="456" prix="36.00" quantité= "241"  />
</liste>
```

My java code :

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp850")); 
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);

   Element racine = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
   NodeList nl = racine.getElementsByTagName("produit");
}
}
```

When I try to compile my java code with javac I have an error telling me :
Attribute name "Quantit╟" associated with an element type "produit" must be followed by the '=' character.

How I can read my french word in my nodelist ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your document does not seem to use the character set it declares in its header.
I can reproduce your problem if the XML document is encoded as UTF-8. The problem goes away if it is encoded as ISO-8859-1. Please try yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-8"); // causes described error
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "ISO-8859-1");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw, true);
    pw.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"); 
    pw.println("<liste>"); 
    pw.println("<produit code='311' prix='43.00' quantité= '28' />"); 
    pw.println("<produit code='123' prix='39.00' quantité= '10'  />"); 
    pw.println("<produit code='456' prix='36.00' quantité= '241'  />"); 
    pw.println("</liste>");
    pw.close();

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp850"));
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

    Element racine = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nl = racine.getElementsByTagName("produit");
}
```

You should make the declared and actual encoding of the XML document match.

Answer (score 0):

Someone found my problem.
It's because my XML is saved with NotePad that Use UTF-8 for encoding.
I use NotePad++ and save it as ISO-8859-1 and my code works fine now.